# Pass by value or reference using struct

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I am fairly new to C++ and I have a question concerning passing elements by reference.
I define the following struct

```
struct Point 
{
        bool isOnEnvelop;
        double x, y;
};
```

And the following function

```
vector<Point> convex_hull(vector<Point> P)
{
        int n = P.size(), k = 0;
        vector<Point> H(2*n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
           // IF SOMETHING ....
                       P[i].isOnEnvelop = true;
                       H[k] = P[i]
                       k++
        }

        H.resize(k-1);
        return H;
}
```

With a main as follows

```
main() 
{ 
     vector<Point> P;
     // FILL P with Point and set Point.isOnEnvelop = false
     vector<Point> H = convex_hull(P);
}
```

The algorithm is building the convex hull of a set of points in 2D space. I want to be able while looping on the elements of P to be able to detect if this point is on the convex hull (therefore checking P.at(i).isOnEnvelop)
Unfortunately the state of the points are not changed after calling the function convex_hull. Should I pass the arguments by reference ? Or should I create P as vector of Point* ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Vincent

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want the modification to `P` to be reflected in `main` after this call `convex_hull(P);`? If that is the case then just pass by reference like this `convex_hull(vector<Point> &P)`.

Comment: yes : actually after calling convex_hull(P) I will loop through P and draw them on a scatter plot (with a different color if the point is in H, therefore being able to check P.at(i).isOnEnvelop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you declared `convex_hull`, the argument is copied:

```
vector<Point> convex_hull(vector<Point> P){ ... }
```

This is very often a bad idea, since copying `P` may be expensive. An alternative for that, if you want to ensure that `P` itself is not modified, would be to use a `const` reference.

If you *want* to modify `P` when calling the function (e.g. have modifications in `main`, you must pass it by reference, and declare `convex_hull` as follows (note the `&`):

```
vector<Point> convex_hull(vector<Point> &P){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `change vector<Point> P` to `vector<Point> &P` so that you can modify vector P.

Answer (score 0):

So after reading your comment, you want the changes to `P` to be reflected in `main` after calling `convex_hull`, so you should just pass it by reference like so:

```
std::vector<Point> convex_hull(std::vector<Point> &P)
```

if you do not pass by reference then the `vector` will be copied and the copy will be modified not the original. Even if you do not want to modify the original you can pass as a `const` reference to gain the advantage of not copying the `vector` like so:

```
std::vector<Point> convex_hull(const std::vector<Point> &P)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your datas are going to be modified, pass reference as argument or give the value instead